# Do not trigger Github action workflow on push if a PR is open on the branch

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflows, one that is triggered on `push` to a branch and the other that is triggered on `pull_request.synchronize`. See the following workflows

```yaml
name: Workflow 1
on: 
  push: 
    branches-ignore: 
      - main
jobs: 
  compile: 
    name: Compile
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps: 
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Compile
        uses: ./gradlew clean compileJava
```

```yaml
name: Workflow 2
on: 
  pull_request: 
    types: 
      - opened
      - synchronize
jobs: 
  build: 
    name: Build and Verify
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps: 
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build
        run: ./gradlew clean build
```

Both these workflows working as expected most of the time, except in the case where a `push` is done on a branch that has an open PR. In such an event, both workflows are triggered.

What I want is that in such a situation, the workflow `Workflow 2` should be triggered while the workflow `Workflow 1` should not be triggered. `Workflow 1` should only be triggered if there is no open PR on the branch. If there is an open PR on the branch, then `Workflow 2` should be triggered.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be solved with just conditions on the trigger, so the workflow will always run in this case, but you can shortcircuit the workflow quickly if you split it into two jobs. Let the first query the PRs and then decide whether to run the 2nd job:

```yaml
jobs:
  detect-outstanding-prs:
    outputs:
      abort: ${{ steps.branchCheck.outputs.abort }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          $outstandingPrBranches = & gh pr list --json headRefName --repo $env:repository | ConvertFrom-Json
          $triggeringBranch = $env:triggeringBranch 
          if (($outstandingPrBranches | ?{ "refs/heads/$($_.headRefName)" -eq "$triggeringBranch" }).count -gt 0)
          {
            "abort=true" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
          }
        env:
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
          triggeringBranch: ${{ github.ref }}
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        shell: pwsh
        id: branchCheck

  build:
    needs: detect-outstanding-prs
    if: ${{ needs.detect-outstanding-prs.outputs.abort != 'true' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          write-output "running"
        shell: pwsh
```

There is a small time-window in which job `build` may run even if a PR was *just* created. But that's probably the closest you'll get.

This is the result:

[image: Workflow succeeded, build job skipped.]

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into quite some scenarios where it makes sense to reduce such redundancy and debounce the workflows.

Jesse already provides a good answer.
The variant below works well for me. It works with bash and is less complicated imho.

```yaml
jobs:
  debounce:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
    outputs:
      abort: ${{ steps.debounce.outputs.abort }}
    steps:
      - name: Debounce
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        id: debounce
        run: |
          pr_branches=$(gh pr list --json headRefName --repo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY)
          if [[ $(echo "$pr_branches" | jq -r --arg GITHUB_REF '.[].headRefName | select(. == $GITHUB_REF)') ]]; then
            echo "This push is associated with a pull request. Skipping the job."
            echo "abort=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          fi

  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    needs: debounce
    if: needs.debounce.outputs.abort != 'true'
    steps:
```

Comment: Two problems: GITHUB_REF may contain "refs/head", causing the search to fail. Further, PRs coming from forks will often originate from branch "master", thus causing the workflow to be disabled for all pushes to master. My current take is to first filter as: pr_branches=$(gh pr list --repo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY -q '.[] | select(.isCrossRepository == false)' --json isCrossRepository --json headRefName);            this_branch=$(echo $GITHUB_REF | sed -e 's/refs\/heads\///')  then grep the latter among the first.